# Login page opened with identity.launchWebAuthFlow doesn't show accounts I logged in

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-api, identity

I'm trying to add user login in my chrome extension. I use own server, which redirects user to `https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount*`.
Generally, it works. But there are no suggested accounts on auth page (screenshot below).

In extension's background script I use `launchWebAuthFlow` to receive token:

```js
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
    interactive: true,
    url: 'http://localdomain.io/auth/login?source=extension',
}, redirectUri => {...})
```

And user redirected to `https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount` page to select account.

When the window with google auth is opened, list of accounts to be logged it is empty. So I need to enter both email and password manually.
[Actual - empty account list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psLvC.png)

But when I open `http://localdomain.io/auth/login?source=extension` directly (in browser) I see a number of accounts I can login with (those I use from time to time to login on different sites) just by click on the account without password.
[Expected (as I receive when open link in browser)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtmhY.png)

And (it should be noted) when I once log in in my extension (with email+password) I can see this email after logout. But must enter password each time. And this list erased after browser reboot.

Question:

Why there are no account on auth page opened via `launchWebAuthFlow` and what should I configure to add them?
Or is it correct behavior and I should it leave as is?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this question?

Comment: Unfortunately no, keep as is.

Answer (score 0):

Because `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` doesn't share cookies with browser, you won't have the logged in account at the first time.

So if you need that, you have to handle the login flow yourself (opening a popup).

But, Google OAuth2 doesn't allow `chrome-extension` schema for redirect URI, you need to have a server (with `https` schema) in the middle to forward the token to your client (extension).